# How to have value of option.parser be passed to some other variable using python?

Tags: python, optionparser

I have python script which is updating the values of variables inside a file, the variable values are curently harcoded but they are to be passed at run time using commandline parameters. My code as follows:

```
    import subprocess
    import time
    import sys
    import string
    from optparse import OptionParser
    from optparse import OptionGroup
    def main():
        usage = "usage: %prog [options]"
        parser = OptionParser()
        try:
            parser = parse_options(parser)
            (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
        except SystemExit:
            return 0
        myfile = open('over.tex','r')
        data = myfile.readlines()
        myfile.close()
        val = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        for i in range(len(data)):
            test_dict = dict( var_Title = "ABC doc"
                              , var_Doc = "136"
                              , var_ECN = "XXXX"
                              , var_date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
                              , var_ProjectName= str(options.project_name)
                              , var_version = str(options.version) )
            test_tuple = ( 'var_Title'
                           , 'var_Doc'
                           , 'var_Rev'
                           , 'var_ECN'
                           , 'var_date'
                           , 'var_ProjectName'
                           , 'var_version'
                           )
            for key in test_tuple:
                print test_dict[key]
                data[i] = data[i].replace((key), (test_dict[key]))                     
        with open('over.tex', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines( data) 
        if options.project_name:
            var = "WELCOME"
        if options.version:
            print "1.1"
    def parse_options(parser):
        group = OptionGroup(parser, "Target options","CMake Target properties")
        group.add_option("", "--project_name", action="store_true",default=False,dest="project_name",help="Project name")
        group.add_option("", "--version", action="store_true",default=False,dest="version",help="Version")
        parser.add_option_group(group)
        return parser

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Now as you can see i am pasing values to the "var_ProjectName" and "var_version" using option.parser but when i execute it on command line as:

```
myscript.py --project_name --version
```

In the file against the varible Project_name and Project_version i get something as follows:

```
Project_name = True
Project_version = True
```

But that is not what i want .I want to to have as follows:

```
Project_name = WELCOME
Project_version = 1.1
```

So, please help how can i have it and what wrong am i doing?
I want to pass values to all the variables from comandilne parameters only so initialy i am only trying with two variables (project_name and version).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `action="store_True"`, specify another [action](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/optparse.html#understanding-option-actions). For example, with

```
group.add_option(
    "", "--version",
    action="store", dest="version", help="Version")
group.add_option(
    "", "--welcome-project",
    action="store_const", const="WELCOME", dest="project_name",
    help="Project name")
```

you can call your program with the arguments `--version 1.1 --welcome-project` and get the options

```
project: "WELCOME"
version: "1.1"
```

Comment: actually the solution which u have suggested in this we need to specify the values on command line (like myscript.py --version 1.1) but i dont want to specify value there. what i want is the script to take value which is specified under section if option.project_name same way for version too. On the command user just need to type myscript.py --project_name --version thats it and have the values of the variables specified. How to have that?

Comment: @Learner I am under the impression that `--welcome-project` in this answer solves your problem. You can set the value you want with `const=`.